# GOOGLEFINANCE in Google Sheets to get high & low and timestamp of high/low from the day I took trade

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-finance

I wanted to keep a track of high/low of a trade from the day I took the trade.
For a day I am able to get high/low but how to get from the date I took my trade which is stored in one of cell.

```
=IFERROR(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2&"","HIGH"))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&C1&"", "ALL",C2 ,C3),"select Col1, Col3, Col4",1)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot, i did a small manipulation against each of my share with below query. 

=MAX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2&"", "ALL",H2 ,I2),"select Col3",1)) ,

=MIN(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2&"", "ALL",H2 ,I2),"select Col4",1))

I have one more small issue when start date in Today()-1, the formula gives an error, if you can help with that also it would really help.

Comment: *"thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot"*.  Glad I could help. As for the *"one more small issue"*, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. While preparing the sheet, do take the time and  -as mentioned before- accept this answer.

Comment: please find a link of my demo sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bTef2aUwHmRTstrHDrh7EGYLKGn-ihVcmr9n7yF6fqs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. Have you solved your issues or still face problems?

Comment: Thanks for looking, but still i am looking for an answer.

Comment: The problem is with your date being a Sunday. No results for Sundays.

Comment: If you see the last row, date been Frida also gives NA, also if you look tomorrow for row number 1, it will provide NA

Comment: I have already added a *"playground"* at your sheet. Change the dates, see how they affect your results and get a better understanding of what to expect.

Comment: currently if you see i have selected start date & End date to be same in your playground, and it's in error state. can you correct the error.